# How to make a WPF Application access online database?

Tags: wpf, database

I am developing a simple WPF Application that requires a database. My question is, can I use an online database to run with my application. That is, can my WPF application access an online database? If yes, then how do I do it? Will the conventional way of accessing the SQL Server work? Also, is there any free online database website available that I can use. I do not need a lot of space. Just need to store 9-10 tables, and about 15-20 stored procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at "SQL AZURE". The call it Database as Service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/dataservices/default.aspx

Additionally you could look at Amazon SimpleDB http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/.